# Prove vertex separator for tree

Tags: graph-algorithm

How to prove every free tree T has a separator S consisting of a single vertex, the removal of which partitions T into two or more connected components, each of size at most n/2?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, any vertex in a tree (except leaves) is a separator. To find a vertex which partitions the tree in "small" components is also quite straightforward.

1. Take any non-leaf vertex 'v' (except the trees with 1 or 2 vertices which are trivial).
2. If 'v' is not "good" then exists exactly one "large" component 'C' incident with 'v'. Moreover, exists only one vertex 'w' in 'C' which is adjacent to 'v'.
3. Take 'w' as the next candidate and repeat step (2).

P.S. Try to do your homework yourself next time.